# Multiple Simultaneous UIViewAnimations on a Single UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewanimation

**Goal**: 
Have several animations play at the same time on a single UIView. 
**Problem**: 
From what I can tell, this is not possible. Each animation has to occur in sequence and cannot overlap.

In essence, I want a single UIView to animate vertically while animating horizontally at the same time. Since I'm using **UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat**, I cannot nest any other animation in **onCompletion:** Here's what I *want* to work but doesn't:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:duration
                      delay:kANIMATION_DELAY
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse animations:^{

                        object.frame = CGRectMake(object.frame.origin.x + 40,
                                           object.frame.origin.y,
                                           object.frame.size.width,
                                           object.frame.size.height);

        [UIView animateWithDuration:duration
                              delay:kANIMATION_DELAY
                            options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse animations:^{

                                object.frame = CGRectMake(object.frame.origin.x,
                                                   object.frame.origin.y - 40,
                                                   object.frame.size.width,
                                                   object.frame.size.height);

                             } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        }];

                    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
}];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is not to use **UIViewAnimation** blocks but instead **CABasicAnimations**. With them you can manipulate the center coordinate (x,y) separately. Here's what my code looks like now:

```
    UIView *view = views[i];

    // Add the horizontal animation
    CABasicAnimation *horizontal = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position.x"];

    horizontal.delegate = self;
    horizontal.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:25.0];
    horizontal.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:50.0];
    horizontal.repeatCount = INFINITY;
    horizontal.duration = 6;
    horizontal.autoreverses = YES;
    horizontal.beginTime = 0; // ignore delay time for now
    horizontal.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];

    [view.layer addAnimation:horizontal forKey:@"horizontal_animation"];

    // Add the vertical animation
    CABasicAnimation *vertical = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position.y"];

    vertical.delegate = self;
    vertical.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:100.0];
    vertical.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:400.0];
    vertical.repeatCount = INFINITY;
    vertical.duration = 2;
    vertical.autoreverses = YES;
    vertical.beginTime = 0; // ignore delay time for now
    vertical.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];

    [view.layer addAnimation:vertical forKey:@"vertical_animation"];
```

This allows me to handle repeat, duration, etc. in two separate animations. Then, when my animations are over, I can just call the follow method to remove animations. Either,

```
    [view.layer removeAllAnimations];
```

or, if I want a more specific animation removed,

```
    [view.layer removeAnimationForKey:@"vertical_animation"];
```

Then, if you want to some more custom control over when the animation starts/stops, you just need to add the delegate methods like so:

```
    -(void)animationDidStart:(CAAnimation *)anim {
        // custom code here
    }

    -(void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)anim finished:(BOOL)flag {
        // custom code here
    }
```

It's pretty sweet and easy. Hope this helps anyone in a similar need. Cheers!

Comment: you left out addAnimation in your for key  [view.layer addAnimation:horizontal forKey:@"horizontal_animation"];