# Animation on CALayer in UIView cancelled when UIView is animated

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, calayer, caanimation

I'm new to Swift (& software development), so go easy please!

I've made a custom class for an 'orb' (donut shape) which will animated in a pulsing manner indefinitely:

```
let layerOne = CAShapeLayer()
let layerTwo = CAShapeLayer()
let layerThree = CAShapeLayer()


override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setupView()
}


required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    setupView()
}

private func setupView() {
    backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    layerOne.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.width, height: frame.height), cornerRadius: frame.width/2).cgPath
    layerOne.lineWidth = 3
    layerOne.strokeColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    layerOne.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    layer.addSublayer(layerOne)

    layerTwo.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.width, height: frame.height), cornerRadius: frame.width/2).cgPath
    layerTwo.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    layerTwo.lineWidth = 9
    layerTwo.opacity = 0.5

    layerTwo.strokeColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    layer.addSublayer(layerTwo)

    layerThree.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.width, height: frame.height), cornerRadius: frame.width/2).cgPath
    layerThree.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    layerThree.lineWidth = 15
    layerThree.opacity = 0.3
    layerThree.strokeColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    layer.addSublayer(layerThree)

    animateOrb()
}

func animateOrb() {
    let layer3Animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "opacity");
    layer3Animation.fromValue = 0
    layer3Animation.toValue = 0.3
    layer3Animation.duration = 0.25;
    layer3Animation.autoreverses = true
    layer3Animation.repeatCount = Float.infinity 
    layerThree.add(layer3Animation, forKey: "opacity");
}
```

I have a UIView on my view controller which has its custom class set to that of my orbView class. The UIView starts as having an alpha of 0, and when I need it, I fade it onto my view using this func:

```
func fade(endAlpha: CGFloat, view: UIView, duration: Double){

    UIView.animate(withDuration: duration) {
        view.alpha = endAlpha
    }
}
```

However, it would appear that by animating my UIView with this function, it kills the animation of my layer, within the view. How do I stop this from happening?

Ideally, I'd like my animated layer within the UIView to keep pulsing, regardless of what happens to the UIView (stretch, fade, relocate etc.)

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Check this SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21036434/multiple-simultaneous-uiviewanimations-on-a-single-uiview